# Photon polarization with respect to quantization axis

Tags: photons, atomic-physics, polarization

I really struggle to understand $\pi$, $\sigma^{\pm}$ transitions.
I am aware that I need a quantization axis to define my angular momentum levels $m_z = \pm\hbar m$. I am also aware that $\Delta m = 0\rightarrow \pi$ and $\Delta m = \pm 1 \rightarrow \pm \hbar m$. I am also aware that a ciruclarly polarized photon carries $+\hbar$ angular momentum and so on.

Based on this understanding, how can a photon that propagates *normal* to the quantization axis have both a $\pi$ and a $\sigma^+$ component?
I don't see where the propagation direction comes into play here, and I am completely lacking an intuitive understanding of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Photon angular momentum obeys the same rules as the electron angular momentum, i.e., when we say that the photon momentum is $\hbar$, we mean that $L^2=\hbar^2l(l+1)=2\hbar^2$ and its projections on the quantization axis are $0, \pm\hbar$.

Another caveat: in an experiment we usually have many photons, but the selection rules account only for the one that is actually absorbed.

Comment: But how is this related to the propagation direction and the photon being able to have both polarizations if its not orthogonal to the quantization axis?

Comment: @LionCereals For free photons one usually chooses the propagation direction as the quantization axis. However, for you the propagation direction doesn't matter: since it is an angular momentum, its components, $L_x, L_y,L_z$ do not commute with each other. This means that whatever axis you chose as quantization axis, you will have projections $\pm \hbar$ (the caveat about photons is that they cannot have $0$ angular momentum projection). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_angular_momentum_of_light